# Rearranging SQL Query Results

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am working on an application that queries a SQL database to get Billing of Material information. I have successfully queried out the data that I wanted using the following query.

```
WITH bom (bomItem, partId, btmlvl)
AS
(
    SELECT [bomItem], [partId], [btmlvl]
    FROM [TESTDB].[dbo].[BOMTABLE]
    WHERE [TESTDB].[dbo].[BOMTABLE].[bomItem] = 'PART# GOES HERE, PASSED IN BY THE APP'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT subQuery.bomItem, subQuery.partId, subQuery.btmlvl
    FROM [TESTDB].[dbo].[BOMTABLE] AS subQuery
    INNER JOIN bom AS mainQuery
    on subQuery.bomItem = mainQuery.partId
)

SELECT [bomItem], [partId], [btmlvl]
FROM bom
```

The query results in (**Sample Data**):

```
bomItem      partId      btmlvl
---------------------------------
1            2            1
1            3            1
1            4            0
1            5            1
1            6            1
1            7            1
1            8            0
1            9            1
1            10           1
1            11           1
8            12           1
8            10           1
8            11           1
8            13           1
8            14           1
8            15           1
8            16           1
4            17           1
4            18           1
4            19           1
```

The data works as follows:

bomItem - The part number of the assembly that I am looking up the bill of materials for

partId - All of the parts and sub-assemblies tied to the bomItem I'm looking up

btmlvl - 0 indicates it's a sub-assembly, 1 indicates a standalone part (not really important, I was just using this to make sure I was getting the results that I wanted)

And what I want it to look like is (Expected Results):

```
bomItem      partId      btmlvl
---------------------------------
1            2            1
1            3            1
1            4            0
4            17           1
4            18           1
4            19           1
1            5            1
1            6            1
1            7            1
1            8            0
8            12           1
8            10           1
8            11           1
8            13           1
8            14           1
8            15           1
8            16           1
1            9            1
1            10           1
1            11           1
```

I could export it to a CSV or something else and write a script to rearrange the data, but I would prefer if it could be done as part of the SQL query. I messed around some with CASE statements but didn't quite achieve the desired results.

Bonus points if it could be aligned as follows (again the btmlvl isn't important, and will ultimately be removed). Again, novice SQL user here, but I think this would be possible using a PIVOT? (I just haven't gotten that far):

```
bomItem      partId      partId2
---------------------------------
...
1            8            
             8            12
             8            10
             8            11
             8            13
             8            14
             8            15
             8            16
...
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, and please excuse the lengthiness of this post!

**EDIT:**

The only difference between my actual data and what I supplied is I simplified the part numbers from 11 characters strings **to** one-digit and two-digit integers and also removed other information I thought was irrelevant (e.g. qty on hand, purchasing cost, etc.). The first set of data **is** the sample data resulting from passing in "1" to `WHERE [TESTDB].[dbo].[BOMTABLE].[bomItem] = 'PART# GOES HERE, PASSED IN BY THE APP'`. This means that the first 10 lines of that data (again, anything with the bomItem == "1"), are all of the parts that make up bomItem == "1".

Looking at the "btmlvl" column for all bomItem == "1", you can see partId's 4 & 8 are assemblies (read sub-assemblies of bomItem == "1"), because btmlvl == "0". This means I need to perform additional queries to obtain the bill of materials for those part numbers. This is where the subQuery within the CTE comes in, giving me the line items starting with bomItem == "4" and bomItem == "8".

The difference between the output as it stands right now, and the output that is desired is the current output lists all parts for bomItem == "1", then all parts for bomItem == "8", and lastly all parts for bomItem == "4".

But what I want is where bomItem == "1" & partId's 1 through 3 to appear as they are right now, but once partId == "4", directly underneath that line I want all of the lines where bomItem == "4", then continue with the lines that contain bomItem == "1" & partId's 5, 6, 7, but again once partId 8 is reached, do a similar thing as with partId 4, then finish partId's 9, 10, 11 as normal.

Comment: If you want the data in a specific order you need to specify an `ORDER BY`. I, however, don't understand the ordering of your expected results, there doesn't appear to be any rhyme or reason for the order of the results you want.

Comment: I'm not sure how to explain it outside of the example I gave, but I will try! The expected results are essentially grouping the partId's that are sub assemblies (aka indicated by the 0 in the btmlvl column) with the parts that make up that sub assembly indicated by the similarly numbered bomItem. This is most obvious if you look at the very last example.

Comment: So how do you know something is a sub assembly? There's nothing in the expected results that denote that.

Comment: I guess maybe the "btmlvl" column isn't as removeable as I thought? But I did explain that the column labeled "btmlvl" is used to indicate whether that part number is a part (1) or an assembly (0). I just figured I would remove it down the line for the sake of cleanliness of the output data. I just figured it wasn't important as I didn't use it within my query and my query worked out properly.

Comment: Perhaps what we rally need here is sample data and expected results, not undesired results and expected results, with no way to get from one to the other.

Comment: An explanation of the logic behind the expected results would help also

Comment: I apologize, I don't understand how what you're asking for is different than what I supplied. I supplied what is essentially the sample data, followed by my goal. I edited my post to clarify some things (I hope!!). The third data set/example is essentially the long term goal, but one step at a time!

Comment: You'll never get to bonus goal in raw sql. That's not how a db operates. But you can definitely get to that point in a reporting tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is inherently hierarchal data, so you need a self-join.

I think this gets you what you want.

```
SELECT a.* FROM bom a
LEFT JOIN bom b
ON a.bomitem = b.partID
ORDER BY ISNULL (b.partID, a.partID), a.partID
```

Comment: As long as there's only one level of nesting. If nesting can go more (or arbitrary) levels, this gets a lot more complicated very quickly.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn yea, in such a case I suppose they would have to write a recursive CTE.  That would be complex, but could be done.

Comment: @RobertSievers this is very close to what I'd like, where it doesn't work however, is the first line where a "b.partId" exists (aka isn't null). I don't know how to explain it other than provide a picture, so here's that.. (I'm not sure if this is frowned upon?) [link](https://imgur.com/FAVOLXd)